# Android GridLayoutManager span size

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am implementing Dashboard in android with Recyclerview and Grid layout manager with 3 items in a row. I will get the dashboard items from server. According to the no of Items, I need to adjust the Recyclerview items to centre.
For example, If I  have 11 items, I need to align last 2 items to the centre. 
If I have , 10 items, last one item need to be aligned centre . For this Logic I made lot of research but didn't find any solution. Even I tried using spansize concept of GridLayoutManager but no luck.
Any help/example code would be very thankful.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, there is no way to accomplish what you want with `RecyclerView` + `GridLayoutManager`. Even if you implement a custom `GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup`, you will only be able to have your extra one or two items *stretch* to fill the row... you can't *center* them.

You can, however, accomplish what you want by using `RecyclerView` with a `FlexboxLayoutManager`, which is a part of Google's **FlexboxLayout** project: https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

When you create your `FlexboxLayoutManager`, you need to set the `FlexDirection` to "row" and the `JustifyContent` to "center":

```
FlexboxLayoutManager manager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(this, FlexDirection.ROW);
manager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.CENTER);
```

Then, when you create your `ViewHolder`s, you need to size them to one third of the `RecyclerView`'s width:

```
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);

    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) itemView.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.width = (parent.getWidth() / 3) - layoutParams.leftMargin - layoutParams.rightMargin;
    itemView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}
```

Here's a link to a gist for a small app that demonstrates this: https://gist.github.com/zizibaloob/0c44bfe59b371b5ae0bd2edcb4a7e592

Answer (score 0):

set `spanSizeLookup` on your `GridLayoutManage`

```
gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            if(ItemList.size() % 3 == 0){
                return 3;
            } else if( ItemList.size() % 3 == 2){
              return 2;
            } else{
              return 1; // number of items to span
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for answer @FarshidABZ, I will try your answer and let you know the output..

Comment: I tried your answer but no luck, nothing has changed. I have 10 Items, My Last Item is still displaying in left corner but not center